# Making command prompt wait

Tags: cmd, batch-processing

```
@call JBOSSbuildWar.bat > ..\logs\JBOSSbuildWar_out 2> ..\logs\JBOSSbuildWar_err

start cmd /c @call WeblogicbuildWar.bat > ..\logs\WeblogicbuildWar_out 2> ..\logs\WeblogicbuildWar_err

start cmd /c @call FEBAPortletWebWar.bat > ..\logs\FEBAPortletWebWar_out 2> ..\logs\FEBAPortletWebWar_err

start cmd /c @call buildStaticJBoss.bat > ..\logs\JBOSSFEBAStaticWar_out 2> ..\logs\JBOSSFEBAStaticWar_err
```

I have this set of batch files getting executed in order. I want to fork out this so that they execute in parallel. I have done that using start cmd /c. Now this will fork out new command prompt window for each of them. Assume there are some set of statements after this. I want to make sure they get executed only after all the forked batch files are finished. How to achieve this?

Lets say average time taken by each file is:
JBOSSbuildWar- 30 minutes
WeblogicbuildWar- 35 minutes
FEBAPortletWebWar- 30 minutes
buildStaticJBoss- 35 minutes

Since the main command prompt window has completed its task in 30 minutes, and the forked batch files needs another 5 minutes to complete, I want the main cmd to wait until the others are done. Kindly help.

Answer (score 3):

there's multiple commands, you can choose what one to use,

**Pause**

Will pause cmd until the user presses any key.
Displays message, "Press any key to continue..."
I use a certain variation of this command called pause>nul.
What it does is pauses the .bat, but doesn't show a message, You just get a blank screen!

**TIMEOUT**

Multiple syntaxes, very useful command, use this one quite a bit. 
Sample code: TIMEOUT 10
Can be bypassed by a key press
Pauses the execution of command by 10 seconds. 
You can also structure it like this: TIMEOUT 10 /nobreak
Which does not allow the user to press a key to skip it, they must endure it!

**Ping**

Very nice one.
Syntax is like this: PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 60000 >NUL
Probably most complex of the three.
PING can be used to delay execution for a number of seconds.

Hope I helped!
-Logan

Answer (score 1):

Easy way:

In your main batch,

```
del "%temp%\*.processfinished" >nul 2>nul
...
start ....whatever1.bat...
start ....whatever2.bat...
start ....whatever3.bat...
...
wait4all:
for /L %%a in (1,1,3) do if not exist "%temp%\%%a.processfinished" timeout /t 1 >nul &goto wait4all
:: continues here when all (3) processes have finished.
del "%temp%\*.processfinished" >nul 2>nul
```

Then in each of the (3) subsidiary `.bat` files, create a file `"%temp%\x.processfinished"` where x=1 for the first process, 2 for the second and so on.

When the sub-processes have started, the procedure waits until each has created its own ".processcompleted" file by checking whether any of the 3 is missing, if it it, timeout for 1 second and look again. Only if the 3 files are present will it continue.

In all probability, it would be best if the subsidiary processes could take an extra parameter (the name of this sub-process's "processfinished" file) rather than having a fixed number for each.

You could extend this, and use say the date and time to augment the filename so that this entire process could itself be run many times in parallel.

BTW - by starting the procedure with

```
@echo off
```

you can remove all of the leading `@`s (all that does is suppress the command-reporting for that *one* line.)

Also, `start` is happier as `start "" .....`, that is, with an empty window title in quotes as its first argument. This allows other arguments to be "quoted" as necessary - the very first "quoted" argument used is used as the "window title" for the process and is likely to be lost to the sub-process. Routinely assigning a dummy (empty if necessary) "window title" means you don't trip over this problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this timer function before each of the commands:

@call JBOSSbuildWar.bat > ..\logs\JBOSSbuildWar_out 2> ..\logs\JBOSSbuildWar_err

Timeout /t 60 /nobreak >nul

start cmd /c @call WeblogicbuildWar.bat > ..\logs\WeblogicbuildWar_out 2> ..\logs\WeblogicbuildWar_err

Timeout /t 60 /nobreak >nul

start cmd /c @call FEBAPortletWebWar.bat > ..\logs\FEBAPortletWebWar_out 2> ..\logs\FEBAPortletWebWar_err

Timeout /t 60 /nobreak >nul

start cmd /c @call buildStaticJBoss.bat > ..\logs\JBOSSFEBAStaticWar_out 2> ..\logs\JBOSSFEBAStaticWar_err

Ps: 60 stands for 1 minute, if you want 30 minutes, change it to 1800